# Issue While setting Faceted Search in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, managed-metadata

I am trying to configure a Faceted Navigation for SharePoint 2013. I have added the Refinement web-part to the page but the **"Use the refinement configuration defined in the Managed Navigation term set"** check box is disabled. Can anyone suggest why is this disabled and how to enable it. Is it necessary to enable this for setting a Faceted Search web-part.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st thing **"You can apply faceted navigation only to publishing sites that use managed navigation."**

if yes then check below.

Navigate to Site settings => Term store management. In the left side column, navigate to Site collection => Product hierarchy. In the tab Intended use, select the checkbox Use this Term Set for Faceted Navigation. Then click Save. 
[image]

after that you will see the option is enable.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/faceted_navigation_in_sharepoint_2013/archive/2012/11/23/configure-faceted-navigation-for-a-product-catalog-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

According to the [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679900(v=office.15).aspx#BKMK_AddRefinementPanel), You have to make sure couple things before adding the web part.

- The managed properties that you want to use as refiners are enabled
  as refinable managed properties as described in "Map a crawled
  property to a refinable managed property in SharePoint site
  collection administration" or "Enable automatically created managed
  properties as refiners in SharePoint Central Administration " [in
  Configure refiners and faceted navigation in SharePoint Server 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679902(v=office.15).aspx).
- You have done a full crawl of the content source that contains the
  managed properties that are enabled as refiners, or indicated that
  your catalog should be fully reindexed during the next scheduled
  crawl of the catalog as described in "Configure search for cross-site
  publishing" [in Configure cross-site publishing in SharePoint Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj656774(v=office.15).aspx)
- If you are using refiners for faceted navigation, you have configured
  the refiners as described in "Add refiners to a term set" [in
  Configure refiners and faceted navigation in SharePoint Server 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679902(v=office.15).aspx).

Comment: I have already checked the check box but still the option is disabled

Comment: this is not easy configuration and one can easily miss a step...i updated the answer please again check it.

Comment: I am working with a Team Site so is it possible to configure the Faceted Search on it.

Comment: that's the problem....You can apply faceted navigation only to publishing sites that use managed navigation.

Comment: I have activated the publishing feature in the Team Site so now will it work or else I need to recreate a new site collection with publishing feature template.

Comment: I am not sure but i would go with new Publishing site collection to avoid any other issue.